# CPU overused vs RAM normal usage, RAM overused vs CPU normal usage

Tags: cpu

I got asked this question in an interview, where they showed me graphs of CPU being overused and RAM being normally used, and graphs of vice versa. What deductions can we make from this, and how can we fix both scenarios?

I mentioned that this was a multiprocessing vs multithreading argument. Is this true?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  What do you mean by "what deductions can we make"?  Can you give us more context?  What kind of answers are  you expecting?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: (Just tried to imagine graphs convincing me of either resource shortage, even *overuse*. "They" need to be knowledgable…) There has been the notion of [(re)computation/memory trade-off](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space–time_tradeoff).